# JavaScript textfield validation: sending focus back

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I am using JQuery and JavaScript for an input form for time values, and I can't make JavaScript to provide the intended reaction to incorrect input format.

What do I do wrong...?

I have a set of 3 text inputs with class "azeit" (and under these a number of others of class "projekt"). All are used to input time values. As soon as the user exits the field I validate the format, do a calculation with it and display the result of this in a field with id "summe1". This works. If the format is incorrect, I display an alert and what I *want* to do is return the focus to the field after emptying it. However, the focus never gets returned (although it will get emptied all right). This is it:

```
var kalkuliere_azeit = function(e) {

  var anf = $("#anfang");
  var ende = $("#ende");
  var pause = $("#pause");
  var dauer_in_min = 0;
  var ungueltiges = null;

  if (nonempty(anf.val(), ende.val()), pause.val()))
  {
    if (!is_valid_date(make_date(anf.val()))){
      ungueltiges = anf;
    };
    if (!is_valid_date(make_date(ende.val()))){
      ungueltiges = ende;
    };
    if (!is_valid_date(make_date(pause.val()))){
      ungueltiges = pause;
    };
    if (ungueltiges)
    {
      alert("invalid time"); //This is where I am stuck
      ungueltiges.val("");
      ungueltiges.focus();
    }
    else {
      dauer_in_min = hourstring_to_min(ende.val())
      - hourstring_to_min(anf.val())
      - hourstring_to_min(pause.val());
      $("#summe1").text(min_to_hhmm(dauer_in_min));
    };
  };

};
....

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".projekt").change( kalkuliere_summe);
  $(".azeit").focusout(kalkuliere_azeit);
});
```

The fields with the class "projekt" are below those with the class "azeit" so they'll get the focus when the user leaves the third field of class "azeit".

I apologize for supplying incomplete source code. I hope someone can *see* what's wrong.

One point I'd like to mention is that I tried binding the handler to onblur and onfocus as well. When I bind it to onfocus the focus does get reset to the field, but the last field the user enters will not update the field $("#summe1") correctly (because this would need focusing another field of the same class).

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure whats wrong with your code but one way of doing it would be to put the focus into a function.

So ...

```
function focusIt()
{
  var mytext = document.getElementById("divId");
  mytext.val("");
  mytext.focus();
}
```

And call it from the if/else statement ...

```
if (ungueltiges)
{
alert("invalid time");
focusIt()      

}
```

Comment: ...nice way of tidying up the source code, but unfortunately doesn't solve the problem. I'm using Firefox 11.0, btw. I added a parameter to the function to make it a general complain function for all elements.